# Flutter app not running on real device android v13 . Too long build or installation or The log reader stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle

[after flutter run cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFSPb.png)

```
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            282.5s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...           4.5s
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on I2207.
```

**DEVELOPER MODE WAS ON **

phone- Iqooz7 android v 13.
flutter version - Flutter 3.7.9

no error in flutter doctor.

Im running a simple counter app.

- flutter run ,

the app will build and then disconnects, as in the above pic.

Even though the application getting installed and launched on the device, it is unable to debug the code

I did -

- gradlew clean build .
- flutter clean.
- uninstalled and then ran
- flutter run -v  flutter doctor showed no error.

nothing  worked. just for a trial purpose , ran a native kotlin app and no error popped up.

then ran the same flutter counter app in other device vivo android v8.
It showed no error and hot reload and restart was working perfectly .

in iqoo the app gets build and disconnects and shows the above error.

Also this is running perfectly in android emulator.

some articles i found -

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117019

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109963

Comment: have you enabled Developer mode on your Android device? Are you able to see the device when you run `adb devices` after you connect it via USB cable?

Comment: yes it was on . Also i ran  the kotlin app to check too .